# XCode Test Target cannot find moduleName-Swift.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a project that uses both Objective-C and Swift. My unit test target is *never* able to find my "moduleName-Swift.h" file.  My app target has no problem with this.

My solution has been this:

1. Press CMD+Space+Click on #import "moduleName-Swift.h"
2. With -Swift.h open - I right click and then click "Show in Finder"
3. I then copy this file to the desktop, and then drag the physical file into my test target in my project.

This stops the errors (as my test target can now use the data in the file), but now my **app** target always points to this file automatically. So whenever I add a new Swift script I have to delete this physical file, and then repeat steps 1-3 or I will not be able to use the new Swift scripts. SUCH A PAIN.

Does anyone know how I can get my test target to point to the auto-generated -Swift.h file?

Comment: Are you unit testing Objective-C classes using Swift unit tests? If so, are your Objective-C classes being included in the test target?

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yes I am doing that, and yes my Objective-C classes are included. What is interesting is any time I create a new class, I have to manually add it to my compile sources in my test target or I get errors

Comment: which version of swift are you using?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing exactly the same problem.